# TextInput Vertical Aligment

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Does anybody know how to fix vertical aligment for TextInput with custom Font (Content and Placeholder)? I tried all these:

- justifyContent: ‘center’,
- alignItems: ‘center’,
- textAlign: ‘center’,
- textAlignVertical: ‘center’,

Nothing works! Any suggestions?

[image]

```
           <TextInput
            ref={ref => this.emailField = ref}
            placeholder="E-Mail"
            style={styles.loginInput}
            placeholderStyle={styles.loginInput}
            editable={true}
            maxLength={40}
            autoCorrect={false}
            selectionColor="#9D9D9D"
            placeholderTextColor="#9D9D9D"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            returnKeyType="next"
            keyboardAppearance="dark"
            textAlign="center"
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordField.focus()}
            value={this.state.email}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ email: text })}
          />

  loginInput: {
    width: '70%',
    height: 40,
    marginBottom: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#dbdbdb',
    fontFamily: 'Neuzeit Grotesk Regular',
    fontSize: 18,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
  },
```

Comment: Did you try lineHeight?

Comment: Can you add the code, what you've done so far?

Comment: I've added the code! @PritishVaidya

Comment: As suggested by @bennygenel, you should try playing with `lineHeight`

Comment: @PritishVaidya Didn't get an acceptable result! Did you?

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution?

Comment: add paddingTop: 0,paddingBottom: 0,to the TextInput style

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  TextInput has a default padding,
  In my case.  I added `paddingTop: 0`, `paddingBottom: 0` to the `TextInput` style.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove marginBottom